Web page is not initializing right when using WebVIew in jetpack compose
Most websites(e.g. Facebook, Google, YouTube) are fine. Some things like the on Image is not!
What's the issue? And why exactly does this website cause this issue?
@Composable
fun WebViewComposable(
    onDivClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                settings.setSupportZoom(true)
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl("https://uni.tsu.ge")
        }
    )
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You never set your WebViewClient.
@Composable
fun WebViewComposable(
    onDivClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                settings.setSupportZoom(true)
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl("https://uni.tsu.ge")
        }
    )
}

